# C# difference between byte[] and char[] format?

Tags: c#

I was wondering those differences, since I have a program that asks me for a byte[].

```
public static string DecryptTextFromFile(String FileName, byte[] Key, byte[] 
IV){}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60nIc.jpg)

and I have already tried:

`char[] key= { '9', 'D', '2', 'A', 'E'};` doesn't give an error but I need byte[]

and this:

`byte[] key= { '9', 'D', '2', 'A', 'E'};` // but this one says that I am using char characters, how do I put them in `byte[]` format?.

Comment: a byte is a series of 8 bits. a char is a character that can be represented by one or more bytes, depending on your encoding. [the documentation might help you understand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: byte[] key = {0x9d, 0x2a, 0xea, ...etc }

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I find that misleading - [`char` in .NET is always 16bits in size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#integral-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a byte array like :

```
byte[] key1 = new byte[] { 57, 68, 50, 65, 69 };
```

Or convert from Char Array :

```
char[] keyChars = { '9', 'D', '2', 'A', 'E' };
var key2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `char` and `byte` are two different types, char size is 16 bit and byte size is 8 bit;
To represent a char you need to convert to bytes.

To do that you can use `BitConverter`

```
 char charValue = 'c';
 bytep[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(charValue);
```

To convert your string from the picture you can use this method

```
static class HexStringConverter
{
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(String HexString)
    {
        int NumberChars = HexString.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) answer will help you